# dot operator on the return value of a function

Tags: f#

Can you apply dot operator on a return value of a function and chain it from there?

for instance

```
type Person = {
    name: string
}

let getPerson =
    let person = {name = "John Doe"}
    person

sprintf "%s" getPerson().name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you apply dot operator on a return value of a function and chain it from there?

It depends on the function's return value. In your case, it's a record type and the answer is yes: you can access its fields with dot syntax.

There are two problems in your example though. `getPerson` is a `Person` record value—not a function that *returns* a `Person` record. In your example, you can just add a unit argument to make it a function:

```
let getPerson () =
    let person = {name = "John Doe"}
    person
```

And you need to wrap your function call and dot-syntax in parentheses to pass it to `sprintf`:

```
sprintf "%s" (getPerson().name)
```